# how to add tokens to gensim dictionary

Tags: python, gensim, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I use [gensim](/questions/tagged/gensim) to build dictionary from a collection of documents. Each document is a list of tokens. this my code

```
def constructModel(self, docTokens):
    """ Given document tokens, constructs the tf-idf and similarity models"""

    #construct dictionary for the BOW (vector-space) model : Dictionary = a mapping between words and their integer ids = collection of (word_index,word_string) pairs
    #print "dictionary"
    self.dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docTokens)

    # prune dictionary: remove words that appear too infrequently or too frequently
    print "dictionary size before filter_extremes:",self.dictionary#len(self.dictionary.values())
    #self.dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=1, no_above=0.9, keep_n=100000)
    #self.dictionary.compactify()

    print "dictionary size after filter_extremes:",self.dictionary

    #construct the corpus bow vectors; bow vector = collection of (word_id,word_frequency) pairs
    corpus_bow = [self.dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docTokens]


    #construct the tf-idf model 
    self.model = models.TfidfModel(corpus_bow,normalize=True)
    corpus_tfidf = self.model[corpus_bow]   # first transform each raw bow vector in the corpus to the tfidf model's vector space
    self.similarityModel = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(corpus_tfidf)  # construct the term-document index
```

my question is how to add a new doc (tokens) to this dictionary and update it. I searched in gensim documents but I didn't find a solution

Answer (score 7):

There is documentation for how to do this on the gensim webpage [here](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html)

The way to do it is create another dictionary with the new documents and then merge them.

```
from gensim import corpora

dict1 = corpora.Dictionary(firstDocs)
dict2 = corpora.Dictionary(moreDocs)
dict1.merge_with(dict2)
```

According to the docs, this will map "same tokens to the same ids and new tokens to new ids".

Comment: this doesn't actually update the dictionary, but rather, creates a transformer, to convert docs in the second corpus to utilize the first dictionary. `add_documents`, in @Ghrua 's example below, actually updates the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `add_documents` method:

```
from gensim import corpora
text = [["aaa", "aaa"]]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(text)
dictionary.add_documents([['bbb','bbb']])
print(dictionary)
```

After run the code above, you will get this:

```
Dictionary(2 unique tokens: ['aaa', 'bbb'])
```

Read the [document](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.add_documents) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

## METHOD 1:

You can just use [keyedvectors](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) from `gensim.models.keyedvectors`. They are very easy to use.

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors

w2v = WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors(50) # 50 = vec length
w2v.add(new_words, their_new_vecs)
```

---

## METHOD 2:

**AND** if you already have built a model using `gensim.models.Word2Vec` you can just do this. suppose I want to add the token `<UKN>` with a random vector.

```
model.wv["<UNK>"] = np.random.rand(100) # 100 is the vectors length
```

The complete example would be like this:

```
import numpy as np
import gensim.downloader as api
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

dataset = api.load("text8")  # load dataset as iterable
model = Word2Vec(dataset)

model.wv["<UNK>"] = np.random.rand(100)
```