# Adding Unknown words to Gensim dictionary and teaching the model

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, tf-idf

I am trying some unknown word and it give out 0% by putting "Polytechnic", "Diploma" that dictionary does not even have and i try to find sources that are able to add words into dictionary that i find are not able to find

Here is my function of code that i am calling

```
def similarityChecker(txt1, txt2):
   result = 0.00
   file_docs = []

   tokens1 = sentence(txt1)
   for line in tokens1:
       file_docs.append(line)

   print("Number of sentence:",len(file_docs))

   gen_docs = [[w.lower() for w in removestop(text)]
            for text in file_docs]

   dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(gen_docs)

   corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(gen_doc) for gen_doc in gen_docs]
   # This tf_idf cannot add unknown words?
   tf_idf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus)

   # Gives out an empty array [] for using words not in the english dictionary
   for doc in tf_idf[corpus]:
       print([[dictionary[id], np.around(freq, decimals=2)] for id, freq in doc])

   # building the index
   sims = gensim.similarities.Similarity('/', tf_idf[corpus], num_features=len(dictionary))

   file2_docs = []

   tokens2 = sentence(txt2)
   for line in tokens2:
       file2_docs.append(line)

   print("Number of sentence:", len(file2_docs))

   avg_sims = []

   for line in file2_docs:
       # tokenize words
       query_doc = [w.lower() for w in removestop(line)]
       # create bag of words
       query_doc_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(query_doc)
       # find similarity for each document
       query_doc_tf_idf = tf_idf[query_doc_bow]
       # print (document_number, document_similarity)
       print('Comparing Result:', sims[query_doc_tf_idf])
       # calculate sum of similarities for each query doc
       sum_of_sims = (np.sum(sims[query_doc_tf_idf], dtype=np.float32))
       # calculate average of similarity for each query doc
       avg = sum_of_sims / len(file_docs)
       # print average of similarity for each query doc
       print(f'avg: {sum_of_sims / len(file_docs)}')
       # add average values into array
       avg_sims.append(avg)

   total_avg = np.sum(avg_sims, dtype=np.float)

   result = round(float(total_avg) * 100)

   if result >= 100:
       result = 100

   return result
```

Some function i added is to call nltk which is working.
And I am new to this gensim coding i really need help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add tokens to gensim dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178843/how-to-add-tokens-to-gensim-dictionary)

Comment: @qaiser The similarity check still give out 0% if the text have that added a new word into gensim dictionary

Comment: share dummy data for txt1 and txt2

Comment: This is txt1 is my model file it can be change in the text document
`txt1 = "Polytechnic " \
       "Diploma " \
       "grade" `
`txt2 = "Dear Polytechnic, I would like to as about my grade"`